# Convert row vector to matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, reshape

I need to write the code that turns a row vector into a matrix. For example, if I had `a = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, I want the matrix to be:

```
m = [1 2 3; 
     4 5 6; 
     7 8 9]
```

I have this, which doesn't work. Can anyone please assist me?

```
for i=1:length(a)
    m = a(i);
    i = i + 1;
end
```

Moreover, I am not allowed to use any of Matlab's built-in functions (such as `reshape`).

Comment: I can't use vec2mat or reshape

Comment: If your vector was 1x8, would the matrix be 2x4, or 4x2? Or is it only for 3x3? If you create a matrix of zeros of the size you want the result to be (for example, `A=zeros(3,3)`) then you can do `A(:)=a`. You will have to check whether the elements go to the right places in the matrix.

Comment: Posting homework assignments is usually not well received on SO, but as you showed what you have tried, +1 =) Have a look at Shai's edit to your question (you can click the "edited x minutes ago" link). Your original loop was not pretty =)

Comment: A note here, for loops automatically steps up the loop index. The loop statement `for i= 1:length(a)` in Matlab is similar to what in java or c++ is `for (int i=1; i<=length(a); i++)`. However, one can assume that the implementation is more sophisticated than that since `for i=a` would perform a similar behaviour to `for (T t : a)`,  where T is its type. So the point is that you do not need to increment `i` in the loop. It is done implicitly in a for loop.

Answer (score 4):

Use reshape

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
A = reshape(a, 3, [])'
```

where the third argument is taken automatically (the number of cols)

Or if you cannot use any MATLAB build in function use this here

```
A = zeros(3,3); %// or A(3,3) = 0 by thewaywewalk (thank you)
A(:) = a;
A = A';
```

Comment: I can't use any MATLAB functions.

Comment: in case `zeros` is also a forbidden function, you could use  `A(3,3) = 0` for pre-allocation.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Are there any case where `zeros(N,M)` actually is preferred over `A(N,M) = 0;`? zeros is of course safer, since this will not modify an existing variable. But still if you are in this situation you are pretty much screwed anyway.

Comment: @patrik [**Here is an extensive article answering your question.**](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance)

Answer (score 3):

Of course, using [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) is the right way to convert a vector into a matrix.
However, since you do not want to use any Matlab function, you can use a loop

```
A = zeros(3,3); %// preallocate
for ii=1:3,
    A(ii,:) = a( (ii-1)*3 + 1:3 ); %// put one row into place
end
```

Or, more generally, if you want to reshape a `H`*`W` vector into a `H`-by-`W` matrix:

```
A = zeros(H,W);
for ii=1:H
    A( ii, : ) = a( (ii-1)*W + 1:W );
end
```

PS,
Note that it is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/1714410).